# MAKE fails to find ft2build.h (freetype2 header) -freetype(2.8.1) is installed properly

Tags: linux, freetype2

I am Trying to compile 'xplanet' R224 (latest version) on Ubuntu 18.04
MAKE fails to find ft2build.h (freetype2 header) I have 'freetype'(2.8.1) installed properly and all the files are there.  I have searched stackoverflow and found many people with the same problem (ft2build.h not found) yet no consensus on why or what the solution is.

Any help is appreciated.

```
MAKE ERROR MESSAGE:
In file included from getTextRenderer.cpp:8:0:
TextRendererFT2.h:4:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
#include <ft2build.h>
compilation terminated.
Makefile:458: recipe for target 'getTextRenderer.o' failed
make[3]: *** [getTextRenderer.o] Error 1


MY INSTALLED FREETYPE FILES:
ls /usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config
ftconfig.h ftheader.h ftmodule.h ftoption.h ftstdlib.h

ls /usr/include/freetype2/freetype
config ftautoh.h ftbzip2.h ftcid.h ftgasp.h ftimage.h ftlzw.h ftmoderr.h ftpfr.h ftstroke.h ftttdrv.h ttnameid.h
freetype.h ftbbox.h ftcache.h fterrdef.h ftglyph.h ftincrem.h ftmac.h ftotval.h ftrender.h ftsynth.h fttypes.h tttables.h
ft2build.h ftbdf.h ftcffdrv.h fterrors.h ftgxval.h ftlcdfil.h ftmm.h ftoutln.h ftsizes.h ftsystem.h ftwinfnt.h tttags.h
ftadvanc.h ftbitmap.h ftchapters.h ftfntfmt.h ftgzip.h ftlist.h ftmodapi.h ftpcfdrv.h ftsnames.h fttrigon.h t1tables.h ttunpat.h

ls /usr/include/freetype2
freetype ft2build.h


MAKEFILE INCLUDES THESE LINES:
FREETYPE2_CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 
FREETYPE2_LIBS = -lfreetype
FREETYPE_CFLAGS =  
FREETYPE_LIBS =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution above was completely successful. FREETYPE2 was misspelled in three places as FREETYPE in "src/Makefile.am" Installation had no further problems

Molly
Feb 27 at 22:50

Answer (score 0):

They have there a mix of FREETYPE and FREETYPE2 variables for some reason. I managed to make it compile with those changes:

In `src/libdisplay/Makefile.am`:

```
--- src/libdisplay/Makefile.am.old      2022-02-27 22:21:56.089575296 +0100
+++ src/libdisplay/Makefile.am  2022-02-27 22:22:13.424197851 +0100
@@ -26,7 +26,7 @@

 EXTRA_libdisplay_a_SOURCES = DisplayMacAqua.cpp DisplayMacAqua.h DisplayMSWin.cpp DisplayMSWin.h TextRendererFT2.cpp TextRendererFT2.h TextRendererPangoFT2.cpp TextRendererPangoFT2.h DisplayX11.cpp DisplayX11.h vroot.h TimerMacAqua.cpp TimerMacAqua.h TimerX11.cpp TimerX11.h

-AM_CPPFLAGS = -I@top_srcdir@/src @X_CFLAGS@ @FREETYPE_CFLAGS@
+AM_CPPFLAGS = -I@top_srcdir@/src @X_CFLAGS@ @FREETYPE2_CFLAGS@

 if USE_AR
   libdisplay_a_AR = $(AR) cru
```

In `src/Makefile.am`:

```
--- src/Makefile.am.old 2022-02-27 22:22:02.953029931 +0100
+++ src/Makefile.am     2022-02-27 22:22:31.438766211 +0100
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@
   parsegeom = ParseGeom.c ParseGeom.h
 endif

-AM_CPPFLAGS = -DDATADIR=\"$(datadir)@separator@xplanet\" @X_CFLAGS@ @FREETYPE_CFLAGS@
+AM_CPPFLAGS = -DDATADIR=\"$(datadir)@separator@xplanet\" @X_CFLAGS@ @FREETYPE2_CFLAGS@
 AM_LDFLAGS = @xplanet_LDFLAGS@

 xplanet_SOURCES = \
@@ -72,5 +72,5 @@
                libprojection/libprojection.a           \
                libsgp4sdp4/libsgp4sdp4.a               \
                @GRAPHICS_LIBS@ @CSPICE_LIBS@ @X_LIBS@  \
-               @XSS_LIBS@ @FREETYPE_LIBS@ @AQUA_LIBS@  \
+               @XSS_LIBS@ @FREETYPE2_LIBS@ @AQUA_LIBS@         \
                @LIBICONV@ @LIBCHARSET@
```

Comment: Your solution was completely successful. installation had no further problems and I am testing now. I will forward your edits to the maintainer for the next upload. Do you think this kind of typo is the cause for so many similar problems with "ft2build.h file not found" issues? if so, we ought to propagate this as a test.
--Molly

Comment: I've never used this project, so I don't know what other problems with "ft2build.h" are there. But there's definitely some mix-up with the variables with and without "2". Maybe  some leftovers from past upgrade or something like that.